# POST Request with raw body always giving me 400 Bad Request

Tags: php

I'm trying to develop a response from a webhook. But as of now the php code is always returning me a 400 Bad Request. I'm trying to emulate the webhook using Postman. Please see image below.

I hope someone could help me and analyze which part is wrong.
tia

[image]

This is my code (zpostget.php)

```
<?php

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$body = json_decode($json, true);

if (is_null($body) or !isset($body['eventName'])) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request');
    return;
}

switch ($body['eventName']) {
    case 'shippingrates.fetch':
        break;
}

header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');

?>
```

Comment: what give var_dump($json) ?

Comment: php://input will not work with redirect, make sure www.samplewebhook.server is the final link, also redirect from http => https also make php://input  unusable

Comment: @svgta var_dump($json) gives NULL, as well as var_dump($body).

Comment: @PhúcHậuTrần samplewebhook.server is my only made-up url, it is not the live url.

Comment: @svgta I modified the code and var_dump($json) now gives this ---->  string(2147) "{
"eventName": "shippingrates.fetch",
"mode": "Live",
"createdOn": "2015-02-21T14:58:02.6738454Z",
"content": {..............

Answer (score 0):

Since, I am not sure about your json data, first bet will be it is malformed json but since your `var_dump($json)` looks like json I am going to assume everything is okay. Here are some tools to be sure

1. **Throw on Exception:**
   Can you add JSON_THROW_ON_EXCEPTION in json_decode and try again ex.
   `json_decode($json, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);`

> var_dump($json) gives NULL

Then you have malformed json

2. **Check json before sending:**Also, please check json that you are sending using a validator, ex. https://jsonlint.com/

unrelated but I will also suggest using `||` instead of `or`.

Last thing would be checking which part of if fails:
so `var_dump(is_null($body))` and `var_dump(!isset($body['eventName']))` and check what is false.

can you share the whole json ?